# Whats does AclProvider::findAcls($oids, $sids) do?

Tags: symfony, acl

What does [`AclProvider::findAcls($oids, $sids)`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Dbal/AclProvider.html#findAcls%28%29) actually do? For me it returns an array (`SplObjectStorage<ObjectIdentities>`). How do I get the ACL's from them?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to get all ACE's for a specific user so I can remove them. eg. On removing of a user. I hope I am on the right track, like using the right function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AclProvider::findAcls()` is used for batch loading ACL's. It's used in circumstances where you have many different objects (eventually object identities).

#### Consider an example

Suppose you have a range of categories and each user can view only a portion of them. To populate a list of categories the user can view, I'd have to check the ACL's.

I'd begin by finding all the categories, the creating an array of object identities (`$oids[] = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($category)`) and then call the `findAcl` method (`$acl_provider->findAcls($oids)`). I can now call `$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('VIEW', $category)` for each `$category` and the application wouldn't query the database anymore as the ACL was preloaded.

---

As for removing all ACE's I think you can delete the whole ACL and the ACE's get removed as well. You'd do this by calling `$acl_provier->deleteAcl($object_identity)`

Comment: So `findAcls()` is just for performance? Not really to get the ACL for the object? Because it returns the ObjectIdentity instead.

Comment: About delete. I think `deleteAcl` will delete all ACE (regardless of user). Suppose I want to delete all ACE on all objects, for a specific user, how might I do that?

Comment: @JMatWork Ah, I just looked into the code and `AclProvider::findAcls` does indeed return the ACLs, in \SplObjectStorage. I've only used it for batch loading. You can take a look in the code yourself - there's [`AclProviderInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Model/AclProviderInterface.php#L48) and [`AclProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Dbal/AclProvider.php#L92). As for deleting all ACE's of a certain users, I'd have to look into it tomorrow.